# How do I correctly set a circle's radius in OpenLayers for a specific unit of measure?

Tags: openlayers-5

I'm trying to create a circle with a specific on-the-ground radius in OpenLayers v5. But I do not seem to understand how to create it with a specific unit of measure such as meters, miles, etc. The radius argument in the constructor appears to be some non-specified map unit, as noted in [this issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6668), which is concluded with using the `getMetersPerUnit` method from the projection. However, everytime this method is called, it always seems to return 1. I've also looked at doing something with the `METERS_PER_UNIT` export in the projection library, but again, the value for meters is 1.

My drawing tries to give a good starting point that's based on the current view's extent. The previous work used 1/8th the lateral distance of the current view.

```
function getRoundedEigthedDistanceBetweenPoints(coordinateA, coordinateB) {
  /**
   * Distance between bottom right and left corners in meters
   * We want 1/8 of the distance, rounded to nearest 10?
   * Why? /shrug ‍♂️
   */
  return (getDistanceBetweenPoints(coordinateA, coordinateB) / 8 / 10) * 10;
}

/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454386/168005
 * @param coordA
 * @param coordB
 */
function getDistanceBetweenPoints(coordA, coordB) {
  return (new LineString([coordA, coordB]).getLength() * 100) / 100;
}

const [minX, _, maxX, __] = map.getView().calculateExtent();

// Since all I want is a straight line, I just give it the minX and maxX values, and zero out the "Y"s. 
const startingDistance = getRoundedEigthedDistanceBetweenPoints([minX, 0], [maxX, 0]);
```

Given the above, I was presuming the result of this `startingDistance` was in meters. But if I compare my circles's values to a normal LineString length, the numbers are off quite a bit.

The problem gets worse when I try to change the radius later from user input, because I was thinking I was working in meters (clearly that's not true), so I convert the values provided down to meters and set it directly as the radius.

```
enum Units {
  Meters = "m",
  Miles = "mi",
  Kilometers = "km",
  Feet = "ft",
}

const METERS_PER_FEET = 0.3048;
const FEET_PER_MILE = 5280;
const METERS_PER_KILO = 1000;

function convertFeetToMeters(feet) {
  return feet * METERS_PER_FEET;
}

function convertMilesToMeters(miles) {
  return miles * METERS_PER_MILE;
}

function convertMetersToKilometers(meters) {
  return meters / METERS_PER_KILO;
}

function convertUnitToMeters(unit: Units, value: number) {
  switch (unit) {
    case Units.Feet:
      return convertFeetToMeters(value);
    case Units.Miles:
      return convertMilesToMeters(value);
    case Units.Kilometers:
      return convertKilometersToMeters(value);
    default:
      return value;
  }
}

function updateFeature({ type, feature, unit, value }) {
  /**
   * Mutably make the change
   */
  if (type === "radius" || type === "unit") {
    // Take in the units listed in the UI and convert the value, respectively.
    const computedRadius = convertUnitToMeters(unit.value, parseFloat(value));
    feature.getGeometry().setRadius(computedRadius);
  }
}
```

I know there's this whole [Web Mercator distortion business](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8778), and using something like [`getLength`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8778#issuecomment-427775065) from the `ol/sphere` module will convert the radius **out** of an already created circle, but what about **setting** the radius of a circle? Is there a tool available for that?

Comment: Web merator projection units are meters but the scale is true only at the equator.  Elsewhere you need to adjust using ol/proj.getPointResolution

Comment: @Mike. Thanks. But, what's the relationship to the result from this function? Do I multiply, divide it by my value? Vice/versa? 

And, do I get the resolution from the map's View?

Comment: Resolution doesn't matter if you only need the ratio for example `ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0])));` returns 1 at the equator and `ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 60])));` return 0.5 at 60 north.  Multiply to convert map units to real distance on the ground, divide to convert distance on the ground to the size needed on a map.

Comment: @Mike. Thank you very much. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If then radius is small like 100km -1000km then there is may be projection issue. I solved it by dividing radius with

```
ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, centerLongitudeLatitude)
```

where **centerLongitudeLatitude** is center of circle.
Here iscode for displaying circle on map

```
geometry:new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude,200*1000/ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, centerLongitudeLatitude)),
```